# Rails: Reordering an ActiveRecord result set

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to retrieve the last five Articles by review date, but I want to display them in chronological order (ascending order).  How do I do this?

```
# controller
@recent_articles = Article.where("reviewed = ?", true).order("review_date DESC").limit(5)

# view
<% @recent_articles.each do |ra| %>
  # articles sorted by review_date in ascending order
<% end %>
```

I tried doing this in the controller, but it retrieved the five oldest `review_dates` instead (i.e. it just retrieved the records by ASC order instead of reordering the array already retrieved):

```
@recent_articles = Article.where("reviewed = ?", true).order("review_date DESC").limit(5)
@recent_articles = @recent_articles.reorder("review_date ASC")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you create a `reviewed` and `recent` scopes in your model. This will allow nicely chain-able scopes in your controllers:

```
# article.rb

scope :reviewed, lambda { where("reviewed = ?", true) }
scope :recent,   lambda { |n| order("review_date").last(n) }

# in your controller..

@recent_articles = Article.reviewed.recent(5)
```

Notice I'm using `last(n)`, not `limit`. There is no point in ordering by `review_date desc` just to get the latest articles by review date, then reorder them because the query was wrong. Unless you're using `review_date desc` for another reason, use `last` instead.

Answer (score 5):

So you want the articles from the DESC query but in the reverse order that they come in from the database?

`@recent_articles.reverse!`